pLotting the correlation between temperature and wildfire in iran
The idea is to find the correlation between wildfires and temperature in iran.
I used the coordinate for each wildfire against the temperature in iran, i mean the geometry but the p-value was very low and almost all the values lied on zero.
I tried the geometry.bound function for only the coordinate of the wildfire but the data llies on zero and p-value is very small

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
